# Paying in cash limit - EU

Tags: european-union, cash, france, spain

Certain EU countries tend to have a limit for cash payments.

For example France and Spain have a limit of ~3000€ for residents and 15.000€ for non residents (tourists). On the other hand, Germany, Malta, Slovenia, and few other countries don't have any limit. [*Source*](https://www.europe-consommateurs.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/eu-consommateurs/PDFs/PDF_EN/Limit_for_cash_payments_in_EU.pdf)

I am curious how is the resident / non resident control enforced in stores?

Ex: A French residency person walks in a Paris shop to buy a ~10.000€ item. How can the clerk know that the person shouldn't be allowed to pay in cash? Asking for the ID won't prove the actual residency.

Comment: What does the limit mean? Your source is talking about shops being *forced to accept cash*. So in Paris maybe the cashier will grumble at you and ask for ID, and then seeing that you're a resident of somewhere else, will begrudgingly accept your briefcase full of tens.

Comment: The cashier will make a sale and purchase agreement. Then the shop will notify the tax office (because the shop need to pay the tax) and they will have data and will be able to check.

Comment: There's no such 3.000 limit. What there is, is an obligation to declare ops 3.000 or higher whenever either part is an _empresario actuando como tal_. Subsect. III in Sect. II in Chapt. V of the Title II. of [RGAT RD1065/2007](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2007-15984).